# set variable current user in script runner database picker is not working

Tags: jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

validation

```
select jiraaccount,displayname from mcigeneralname where jiraaccount = ?
```

search sql

```
select jiraaccount,displayname from mcigeneralname 
where lower(jiraaccount) like lower(?) || '%'
```

configuration script :

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.option.Option
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.jira.fields.editable.database.SqlWithParameters
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;


def userinfousername = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser().getUsername()
String userinfo = userinfousername


getSearchSql = { String inputValue, Issue issue, String originalValue ->

     new SqlWithParameters(
        "select jiraaccount,displayname from mcigeneralname  where jiraaccount like ? || '%' and jiraaccount = ?",
        [inputValue,userinfo]
    )
}

getValidationSql = { String id, Issue issue,String originalValue ->

    new SqlWithParameters("""
        select jiraaccount,displayname from mcigeneralname
        where displayname = ? and jiraaccount = ?
        """
        , [id, userinfo])
}
```

when I set the string to user info it's works
Ex:
userinfo = 'm.moeini' it works but when set as get current user is not working